# What is the correct way to save any object as a generic Map<String, Object> in Jackson?

Tags: java, paypal, jackson

I'm trying to save a copy of a class in generic `Map<String, Object>` form for an external data type:

```
Map<String, Object> test1 = objectMapper.convertValue(payoutBatch, 
                                              new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});

Map<String, Object> test2 = objectMapper.convertValue(payoutItemDetails,
                                              new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

`PayoutBatch` and `PayoutItemDetails` are both imported from the PayPal payments Java SDK and thus can't be annotated. But trying to convert them gives:

```
Class com.paypal.api.payments.PayoutBatch not subtype of 
[map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.Object] ->
[simple type, class java.lang.Object]]
```

I'm still pretty new to Jackson so is this even possible? Would like to know.

Comment: try `new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){}`

Comment: I tried storing it as a `Map<String, String>` but this produces an error when writing the map to JSON when trying to convert nested values. For instance, if the map has an inner map which has an entry that is an arraylist you get `can't convert arraylist to string` error.

Comment: I don't think you can make it generic. Maybe you shall create java type from `TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(Map.c‌​lass, String.class, Object.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that given a valid Map where Object in turn could be any primitive, or List or Map you know how to serialize it to JSON using Jackson, this is trivial. So I would suggest that you create an interface (say call it Mappable) with single method:

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap();
```

And then any class that you wish to serialize to JSON using Jackson should implement this interface. Each class would then implement a method that would produce the Map that represents your class and then you can pass this Map to serialization.

Comment: Hi Michael,

Unfortunately, per my post, I was mostly interested in third-party classes where I am unable to modify the source code. The examples I used were PayoutBatch and PayoutItemDetils, both of which are imported via the PayPal Payment Java SDK.

Comment: OK, then I would write my own Utility class that can take those classes and create their map representation. Then you can serialize the map

Comment: Definitely doable. I was wondering if there was a generic way of converting any class C to its map representation M and then to and from the map's JSON representation J at any time. So it would look something like this: `C -> M <-> J` or `Class -> Map <-> JSON`. If you come up with any ideas let me know! My intent is to 'archive' entire classes as they're represented. This could in essence allow one to save an entire generic REST API response that has been marshaled to its Java class representation. I got really far but I think my lack of Java generics and jackson expertise were too great.

Comment: Well, there is no generic out of the box way to serialize any class to it's map representation. If it is your class then you can use Jackson and it's annotations to tell Jackson how your class should be converted. In most cases you can do it all with annotations without writing any additional code. As for out of the box serialization for any class, If that class implements Serializable interface then it could be serialized and de-serialized to/from java internal format, but that format is not guaranteed be kept from java version to version. Read more on Serializable interface.